# How can I remove command line option for single file in the visual studio c++ project?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, command-line

I tried to use _penter() function.
This function needs "/Gh" options, so I added "/Gh" options at the project file.
After that, "/Gh" option applied to cpp file that contains _penter() function,
so this function(_penter) called itself continuously.
It cause stack overflow.

If I add "/Gh" options at one cpp file, it worked well.
But there are so many cpp files,
so I tried to apply on the project file but one file that contains _penter() function.

I use visual studio 2015 version.
is there any way?

Comment: I'm more interested in knowing *why* you need the `_penter` function. What problem is adding this hook supposed to solve?

Comment: I'd like to chase all of the function in the project. I want to get function sequence flow, but there are over 10000 functions that our team made. I thought using _penter function was easiest way to trace all the functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could remove directly: `right click .cpp ->properties -> c/c++ -> All Option -> Additional Options`.

[image]